# php uppercase post_title wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, menu, uppercase

I'm have a website on Wordpress.
I have a  menu displayed on my children pages.
everything works perfectly.
I have also an Index A, B, C, etc... in  format.
In my css, everything is in Uppercase. it works on Chrome, Firefox, but not in Safari for example, the options in my menu are in lowercase.
So I would need to enter my page tittles myself in Uppercase... which is no the best solution I guess....
so I would like to add a php function to uppercase my post_title instead of using CSS to do it.
I know I can use the "strtoupper" function but I don't know who to use it in this case :

```
echo '<select name="" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
```

here is mu full php code building the menu :

```
<div class="styled-select">
<?php

if(!$post->post_parent){

    $children = get_pages(array(
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    ));

}else{

    $children = get_pages(array(
        'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    ));
}

if ($children) {
    echo '<select name="" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
    echo '<option>'. 'A - Z' .'</option>';

    function getInitials($name){
    //split name using spaces
    $words=explode(" ",$name);
    $inits='';
    //loop through array extracting initial letters
    foreach($words as $word){
        $inits = strtoupper(substr($word,0,1));
        break;
    }
    return $inits; 
}
$currval = "";

    foreach($children as $child){
        //print_r($child);
        $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
        $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
        if($initial!='' && $currval != $initial ) {
            $currval = $initial;
            echo '<optgroup label="'.$initial.'""></optgroup>';
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';


} ?>


<!-- FIN MENU DEROULANT A-Z -->


</div>
```

here is a jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/3LZEt/

if anybody can help me !
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The displayed option text should not have anything to do with your redirect not happening.

Did i understood correctly that the redirect is indeed what is troubleing you?
And that you tried safari mobile? if so it doesnt support the onchange, but onblur

```
echo '<select name="" onblur="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
```

But this breaks the other browsers i think, so a switch for working browsers and non working ones would be needed to onchange for one and onblur for the other.

**EDIT**
Please see this part, there you have your post title

```
foreach($children as $child){
    //print_r($child);
    $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
    $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
    if($initial!='' && $currval != $initial ) {
        $currval = $initial;
        echo '<optgroup label="'.$initial.'""></optgroup>';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
}
```

So, use this instead

```
foreach($children as $child){
    //print_r($child);
    $permalink = get_permalink($child->ID);
    $post_title = strtoupper($child->post_title);
    $initial = getInitials($child->post_title);
    if($initial!='' && $currval != $initial ) {
        $currval = $initial;
        echo '<optgroup label="'.$initial.'""></optgroup>';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$permalink.'">'.$post_title.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: hello Basti, thanks for your reply. I don't have trouble with redirecting. my menu works perfectly on every browsers. I just want to display my page titles (which are inside my <select> menu) in uppercase. it works with css (text-transform:uppercase) on chrome & firefox, but Safari display my titles in lowercase... so I just wanted to add a php function to display my pages titles in uppercase, without using css, I guess I can use "strtoupper", but I don't know how to make it works in my code, so nothing to do with redirection, only a function to transform my page titles in uppercase, you see ?

Comment: thanks a lot Basti, uppercase works now fine, but my pages are not sorted alphabetically anymore... do you know why ?

Comment: @user2836404 hmm, might be cos of the `$initial = getInitials($child->post_title);` Could try instead of using child post title there to use `$post_title`